# Observables in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am new to Angular 8 and I am facing one issue in Angular.

I have two-component one is `discussion component` and another is the `topic component`.
the discussion comment has another sub-component called `add-files component`
and the `add-topic component` is the sub-component of the `topic component`.

I want to create an observable in the add-files component that will get notified whenever I click on a button in the add-topic component.

what I did you can see below.

**add-files.component.ts**

```
@Input()
  fileEventsAdd: Observable<void>;
  private fileEventsSubscriptionTopic:Subscription;


ngOnInit() {
this.fileEventsSubscriptionTopic = this.fileEventsAdd.subscribe(
      ()=> this.uploader.clearQueue()
      );
}
```

Now the observable that I created in the add-files.component.ts files that I need to call from the `add-topic component`(which is the ***sub-component*** of the `topic component`) but I don't know how can I do this?

the topic and discussion component are at the same level but the add-files component is the sub-component of the discussion component and the `add-topic` component is the sub-component of the `topic component`.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You need a service at their mutual ancestor.

Comment: @ritaj can you please show with example? I am new to this and I don't know about this.

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: Can you please add all relevant code. It's generally helpful to demonstrate your setup with some example code (and a stackblitz demo, ideally)

Comment: Also, I don't get why parent can't just subscribe to the observable if it is also passing it in to the child via in `@Input()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just follow the below steps

1) create a subject as Observable in your service file and inject that in your respective components.

2) then create a subscription on the `ngOnInit()` method for these components. so that it will keep on listening if any changes are there.

3) Whenever you click on the add button from your topic file component. you can call that method and emit the data with the `next()` method from your service file.

4) so the components which are subscribing will get the data.

5) can you check below [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example-9bvyse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fuser.service.ts) for your reference.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no reason for using Observable/Subscription. Better you should show some code.
Basically, you need to restructure components and use Input/EventEmitter instead.

[EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

[OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)